# SQL clause: newbie question

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
culture   street
------------------------
es        Calle Roma 15
eu        Via Roma 15
es        Calle Paris 20
eu        Via Paris 20
```

Is possible to create an SQL query that retrieve first the rows that the value "es" (in the field culture of course) and the rows that the value "es"?

Comment: Both filter criteria that you specify are the same, no?

Comment: @Noel Abrahams: it's likely a typo and he meant to write "eu" for the second query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve this. One of it is to use [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

```
select * from tbl where culture = 'es'
UNION
select * from tbl where culture = 'eu'
```

Answer (score 3):

If your table only contains es and eu cultures you can just do an order by

```
select * from tbl
order by culture
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from tbl where culture = 'es' or culture = 'eu'
order by culture
```

should also do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you wanted something like this:

First of all, to retrieve the rows that has the value "es" in culture column, you need to write the following query -

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE culture = "es"
```

Next, I am assuming you wanted to retrieve the rows that has the value "eu", you made a typo here. Same query -

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE culture = "eu"
```

And please mention the table name whenever you are asking questions regarding SQL and SQL Query.